# Options to route bathroom exhaust fan

Tags: bathroom, exhaust-fan

I am trying to install a bathroom exhaust fan but I am not seeing a real good way to get outside.  The first picture below shows my ideal spot for the fan represented by the new work box. If I were to run the along the joist and put a hole on the other side of the insulation you see that would put the vent directly under the bay that leads out onto my patio.

Looking at the second picture, to get out from under the bay I would need to mount the inside the ceiling above the tub. The biggest problem with that is that are water lines running along that joist that I would have to navigate around.

Looking at the third picture shows my ideal placement for the vent: to the left of the water line that runs out onto my patio.  I am trying to avoid boxing out an area to run the vent but I know that I can't run a 4" exhaust pipe through the joist.

Does anyone see any other options here?  Could I run a rigid pipe out under the bay, put a 90 on it, and then run another length to get out from under the bay?  Is there something else I could do?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Out the bay in photo 1 are there any windows above that space, I have put vents on external walls like that but in my jurisdiction a window cannot be above or below the exhaust point.

Comment: @EdBeal The bay has patio doors that open onto stairs made out of pavers.